# Sequence of contraction mapping and convergence of fixed point

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, contraction-operator, arzela-ascoli

Let $(,||_{\infty})$ be a metric space and $ : →$ be a function mapping S into itself. $S$ is a space of bounded and Lipschitz continuous function.

For each $\inℕ$, $\tau_{n}\in T$ satisfies the Blackwell sufficient conditions, which implies the existence of unique fixed point. Let $s_{n}$ be the fixed point function of each $\tau_{n}$.

Suppose $\{\tau_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $\tau_{0}$, with fixed point $s_{0}$.

Unfortunately, here I am not sure ***what type of convergence*** is required, but what I want to show is the following :

For any $u \in S$,
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \tau_{k} \circ \tau_{k-1} \circ ...\circ  \tau_{1} (u)=s_{0}$$

The only references that I could find was about $\{s_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \rightarrow s_{0}$. I thought that my conjecture might hold because of the convergence of mappings and the continuity of output functions. There must be some $N \in  ℕ$ which guarantees $\tau_{N}$ to be a sufficiently similar contraction mapping to $\tau_{0}$, and as we keep applying $\tau_{n>N}$, the input function converges to the fixed point of $s_{0}$.

---

Ali left an answer, which I believe correct at the moment. Regarding $\{s_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \rightarrow s_{0}$, I leave the following theorem just in case some of you find needed; the proof is by F.F Bonsall "Lectures on Some Fixed Point Theorems of Functional Analysis".

[Theorem]
Let $S$ be a complete metric space, and let $\tau_{0}$ and $\tau_{k}$ be contraction mappings of S into itself with the same Lipschitz
constant $\beta < 1$, and with fixed points $s_{0}$ and $s_{k}$  respectively. Suppose that $lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \tau_{k}(u) = \tau(u) $ for every $u \in S$. Then $lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} s_{k}= s_{0} $

At the end, the uniform Lipschitz constant for every $\tau_{k}$ seems to be an essential condition.

Comment: So as I understand it, you have already concluded that $s_{n}\to s_{0}$? Can we also assume that the Lipschitz constants for $\{\tau_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are bounded above by a constant less than one? i.e. that for some $\beta<1$ we have $\lVert \tau_{k}(u)-\tau_{k}(v) \rVert \le \beta \lVert u - v \rVert$ for all $k,u,v$

Comment: To apply Arzelá-Ascoli you would need a *compact* metric space.

Comment: @Ali  / Hi Ali!, I was more or less sketching the proof, so $s_{n} \rightarrow s_{0}$ might need a stronger condition, but I could find two references proving it. I remember it requires a pointwise convergence of $\tau_{n}$.

Comment: @Ali I have to check with my real problem, but please assume as you may wish. At the moment, I am completely lost about all the exact sufficient conditions to guarantee the result.

Comment: @Jochen / You are right. The discussed space in my problem is only complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $u_{n}$ according to $u_{k+1}=\tau_{k+1}(u_{k})$.
Assume, as suggested in the comments,
\begin{equation*}
  \lim_{k\to\infty}\lVert s_{k}-s_{0}\rVert=0\qquad\text{and}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  \exists \beta\in(0,1)\quad\text{s.t.}\quad\lVert\tau_{k}(u)-\tau_{k}(v)\rVert \le \beta \lVert u - v \rVert
  \quad\text{for all }k,u,v.
\end{equation*}
Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Choose $\delta$ such that
$\delta/(1-\beta)<\epsilon/2$ and $n$ such that $m\ge n$ implies
$(1+\beta)\,\lVert s_{m}-s_{0}\rVert<\delta$.
Then for $m \ge n$ we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \lVert u_{m+1}- s_{0}\rVert 
  &\le& \lVert \tau_{m+1}(u_{m})-\tau_{m+1}(s_{m+1})\rVert
  +\lVert s_{m+1} - s_{0}\rVert \\
  &\le& \beta \lVert u_{m}-s_{m+1}\rVert
  +\lVert s_{m+1} - s_{0}\rVert\\
  &\le& \beta \lVert u_{m}-s_{0}\rVert
  +(1+\beta)\lVert s_{m+1} - s_{0}\rVert.
\end{eqnarray*}
With $x_{n}=\lVert u_{n}-s_{0}\rVert$ and
$x_{m+1}=\beta x_{m}+\delta$ for $m\ge n$,
we have $x_{m}$ an upper bound for $\lVert u_{m}-s_{0}\rVert$.
In fact
\begin{equation*}
  x_{n+k}=\beta^{k}x_{n}+\frac{1-\beta^{k}}{1-\beta}\delta
  < \beta^{k}x_{n}+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon.
\end{equation*}
So just choose $k$ such that $\beta^{k}x_{n}<\epsilon/2$
and for all $m\ge n+k$ we will have $x_{m}<\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Just a quick question. Here the norm $||$ is the sup norm $||_{\infty}$. Is it?

Comment: Any norm suffices for this argument.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for leaving the answer. I could review a bit more carefully.

Comment: Well for an infinite sequence there won't necessarily be a $\max$. Instead one uses $\sup$. But it is possible that every $\beta_{k}<1$ while $\sup_{k}\beta_{k}=1$. So that could cause a problem here. Edit: replied to a comment that disappeared!

Comment: Thank you very much!